# Change demonstrated texts(strings) of DatePicker in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8, java-time

I'd like to change some demonstrated values of `DatePicker` in `JavaFX`.

For example notice to below picture:
[image: The picture is downloaded from Oracle Web Site]

If i want to change the color and text of `DateCell` of current Date, it's seems to be very easy because you can do it by below code:

```
private DatePicker dateTest = new DatePicker();
final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>()
        {
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker)
            {
                return new DateCell()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (MonthDay.from(item).equals(MonthDay.of(9, 13)))
                        {
                            setTooltip(new Tooltip("It's going to be change"));
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff4444;");
                            setText("Elyas");
                        }
                        if (item.equals(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                        {
                            // Tomorrow is too soon.
                            setDisable(true);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        };
  dateTest.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
```

the result of the above codes become something like below picture:
[image]

so as you can see changing the text and color of `DateCell` ( in this case 25th of 
September) is not very hard.

but my question is how can i change other part of the `DatePikcer`? For instance i would like to change

"September" to "Hello"

"sun" to "1"

"mon" to "2"

"2013" to "year container"

Comment: why? All its data are LocalDate, so the texts should be ... date related and recognizable as such. There's no month called _Hello_ in any language I know :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Yes you are true, actually JavaFX's DatePicker does not support Gregorian calendar, so i need to translate and change it's number to my Gregorian. I just say Hello just for simplicity, as you can guess i need to reconstruct its values

Comment: don't understand (no expert in calendars, so can be completely off :-) - the new date system _is equivalent to the proleptic Gregorian calendar system_ what exactly do you need? BTW: it's your only chance to somehow configure the chronology, all cells (except the dayCell) are hard-coded in DatePickerContent with hard-coded formatters - can't see any way to change that (except implementing a custom skin with a custom content from scratch)

Comment: @kleopatra: ooops are you sure? do you mean the only cells that can be changed are `dayCel`?? :(

so in this situatation i need to implement a new `DatePicker` instead of using( trying to change) JavaFX's `DatePicker`

Comment: have a look at DatePickerSkin/DatePickerContent - that's what I see. Anyway, still don't understand your requirement: are you handling historical dates or why else is standard ISO calendar not applicable in your case? Please add a clarification to your question

Comment: @kleopatra: check this [JalaliCalendar](http://github.com/amirmehdizadeh/JalaliCalendar), by this class i can simply change US-Calender to Iranian-Calender. the only thing that i need is to change cell's value, and show them in a Persian for example today is : 8th May but i instead of May I want to show اردیبهشت. by changing the value and translate them in Persian, Iranian user can choose their target date. and when i want to save it in database i convert it to US-Calender form...

Comment: repeating: please add the clarification to your question - might attract a calendar expert :-) I think you need a chronology implementing the persian calendar, and then let your Persian Locale (could be custom, provided via a serviceProvider) vend that chronology - all date-related text is formatted locale-aware, so should be correct automatically. Just a guess, never did it.

Comment: The requirement is legit. for example, some user prefer "Sept" over "September".